# Jenkins + Maven release plugin: release:branch + Git - Unable to commit files

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, gitlab

I'm trying to make a release using the Maven release plugin, but I get an error

```
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
[ERROR] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

**In my pom.xml such settings:**

```
 <scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@git.domain.ua/myproject/mylib.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://git.domain.ua/myproject/mylib</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

**My Jenkins job settings:**

Repository URL: ssh://git@git.domain.ua/myproject/mylib.git

Credentials: my ssh-key also imported in Git repo as deploy key

Branch Specifier (blank for 'any'): */development

Maven Release goals and options: -Dresume=false release:branch javadoc:javadoc

DryRun goals and options: -Dresume=false -DdryRun=true release:prepare

As you can see from the logs, Git-plugin successfully clones a branch, but Maven cannot make a commit for some reason:

```
   Cloning the remote Git repository
    Cloning repository ssh://git@git.domain.ua/myproject/mylib.git
     > git init /opt/jenkins/workspace/MYJOB # timeout=10
    Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@git.domain.ua/myproject/mylib.git
     > git --version # timeout=10
    using GIT_SSH to set credentials JENKINS(jenkins user with jenkins@USER)

    git checkout development
    Switched to a new branch 'development'
    Branch development set up to track remote branch development from origin.
    Parsing POMs
    Established TCP socket on 44626

[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /opt/jenkins/workspace/MYJOB && git push ssh://git@git.domain.ua/myproject/mylib.git refs/heads/development:refs/heads/development

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:branch (default-cli) on project MYPROJECT: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[JENKINS] Archiving /opt/jenkins/workspace/MYPROJECT/pom.xml to *****-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
[ERROR] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I guess Maven doesn't know anything about the key that uses the Git-plugin, but I can't figure out how to configure the Maven Release Plugin to use the same key?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this in your Jenkins job configuration:

1. Update the **Branch Specifier (blank for 'any')** to the syntax `refs/heads/development`.
2. Under **SCM** > **Git** > **Additional Behaviours**, select **Checkout to specific local branch** and then enter `**` as the branch name.
3. Under **Build Environment**, select **SSH Agent** > **Specific credentials**, and then specify the same SSH key that you used for cloning the repository.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the clone via **https** protocol and the push via **ssh** protocol. You must define which protocol to use for the transfer. For comparison, use the result of the command: `git remote show origin`, with the scm parameter set in the **pom.xml** file.
Example:

```
<scm>
   <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:user/repo-name.git</connection>
   <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:user/repo-name.git</developerConnection>
   <url>git@github.com:user/repo-name.git</url>            
   <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it did not help, the error still exists. I played with different options, but unsuccessfully

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the ssh:// and just use : scm:git:git@git.domain.ua/myproject/mylib.git
replace the url tag by a connection tag with the value : scm:git:git@git.domain.ua/myproject/mylib.git

In the end it's gonna be something like this :

   scm:git:git@git.domain.ua/myproject/mylib.git
 scm:git:git@git.domain.ua/myproject/mylib.git

Also the plugin is searching for a project "MYPROJECT" uppercase ,  or i guess in gitlab youhave "myproject", you can check and change all "MYPROJECT " reference to "myproject" and then try again.

Best regards,